# How to replace an UNKNOWN Word after a specific word with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named `const.lib` which includes parameters and passwords.
My file looks as follows and I want my DB-admin to update the password (which I don't know) assigned to the parameter `vORAPASS` without opening an editing manually my file.

```
if [[ $ZONE = "developement" ]]
 then

 declare -rx vLEVEL=DEV

    declare -rx vORACONSTR=run.dev.zone
    declare -rx vSORAUSER=master
    declare -rx vORAPASS=KNOWNPASSWD
    declare -rx vORASCHEME=master
        ...


elif [[ $ZONE = "test" ]]
 then

 declare -rx vLEVEL=TINT

    declare -rx vORACONSTR=run.tint.zone
    declare -rx vSORAUSER=master
    declare -rx vORAPASS=UNKNOWNPASSWD
    declare -rx vORASCHEME=master


elif [[ $ZONE = "production" ]]
 then

  declare -rx vLEVEL=PROD

    declare -rx vORACONSTR=run.prod.zone
    declare -rx vSORAUSER=master
    declare -rx vORAPASS=UNKNOWNPASSWD
    declare -rx vORASCHEME=master
       ...

fi
```

How can I use sed for this to change the 3rd occurance only?
THX in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` and backreferencing:

```
sed -r 's/(vORAPASS)(=.*)/\1=MY_NEW_PASS/' const.lib
```

Or without backrefrencing:

```
sed 's/vORAPASS=.*/vORAPASS=MY_NEW_PASS/' const.lib
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}/vORAPASS/{$2="NEW_PASS"}1' const.lib
```

For replacing the third occurance of the `vORAPASS` You can use:

```
awk '/vORAPASS/{c++ ;if(c == 3) gsub(/vORAPASS=.*/,"vORAPASS=MY_NEW_PASS")}1' const.lib
declare -rx vORACONSTR=run.prod.zone
declare -rx vSORAUSER=master
declare -rx vORAPASS=UNKNOWNPASSWD #<----------1st its not
declare -rx vORASCHEME=master
declare -rx vORAPASS=UNKNOWNPASSWD #<----------2nd its not
declare -rx vORAPASS=MY_NEW_PASS   #<---------3rd replaced
```

For doing inplace replacement: Check your `awk` version, in ver 4+ it support inplace replacement as `sed` does. If there is no inplace replacement in your `awk` then :

```
awk '/vORAPASS/{c++ ;if(c == 3) gsub(/vORAPASS=.*/,"vORAPASS=MY_NEW_PASS")}1' const.lib > temp && mv temp const.lib
```

Comment: Dear PS, 

thank you for your very fast and good answer. 
I forgot to ask for the immediate save-option and that unfortunately the parameter occurs within if-else statements several times in my file.
So how can I change for instance only the 3rd occurance of that parameter and save it immediately to my file?

Greetings from Cologne / Germany :)

Comment: For immediate saving you can use `sed -i.bac 's/........` . for other query could you add some example in question for our understanding ?

Comment: IF I understood correctly then `awk '/vORAPASS/{c++ ;if(c == 3) gsub(/vORAPASS=.*/,"vORAPASS=MY_NEW_PASS")}1' const.lib` will do the work for you.

Comment: Hi PS, I just updated the description of my question, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Cologne2202 check my update in above answer, does it help ?

Comment: Your awk statement works :) But how can I save the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138904/discussion-between-cologne2202-and-ps).

Answer (score 0):

@PS, thank you for your support, my problem is completely solved now :)